# Javascript: How can I access the ImageData data properties when generated as a function?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following case where I have a base64 image that I want to turn into an array and access its properties.

While the code works, I am unable to access its properties like so:

```
console.log('imageData', imageData)
```

What can I do to get at the underlying data?

A MWE:

```
    var str = "data:image/png;base64,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"
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var image = new Image()
    image.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
      var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
      // only works here, but cant use later
      console.log(imageData)
    }
    image.src = str;
    console.log('imageData', imageData)
```

If I run the code as follows; it will not run 100% of the time:

```
    var image = new Image()
    image.src = await str;
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
    console.log('imageData', imageData)
```

Yielding:

`Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source width is 0.`

Comment: Two mistakes, [the scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500431/1169519) and [async execution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1169519).

Comment: Well, I didn't mean async execution itself was a mistake, rather that you've to learn how to handle it correctly.